# How do I install eopkg on Ubuntu Budgie

Tags: package-management, budgie

I am trying to build my own applet, but I am getting a dependency error. To resolve it I need to get eopkg. But how do I install it, apt won't work.

Comment: What's `eopkg`?  I can't find any info on it.

Comment: https://solus-project.com/articles/package-management/basics/en/ It is the package management tool used by Solus.

Comment: Are you using Solus OS or Ubuntu?  Solus OS is offtopic here, and if you are on Ubuntu, it seems `eopkg` isn't available in Ubuntu and is a Solus-specific thing, from what little searching I've done so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what research I've done on this (and there's not much out there to look at in terms of `eopkg` resources that *are not* Solus OS-centric), `eopkg` seems to be a Solus OS specific package manager.  It does not work with Debian style `.deb` packages, nor does it work with RHEL-style `.rpm` packages, and is not available in Ubuntu.

There does not seem to be any specific upstream project that I can find which has `eopkg`, and it seems to be Solus OS-specific.  I do not believe that you can install `eopkg` in Ubuntu (and I can't say if it even compiles properly in an Ubuntu environment, because the source code doesn't seem to be published on GitHub anywhere), so if your application / applet is *dependent* on `eopkg`, then it's likely a Solus OS-only application/applet and will not work with Ubuntu.

Comment: Budgie is a Desktop Environment for Ubuntu, and applets run just fine(infact I am running a couple of them). But yes I guess eopkg won't work on Ubuntu and hence I guess the applets can't be built on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Rahul *Budgie* is a DE, yes, but **under the hood** the OSes are different.  `eopkg` is Solus-specific based on the research I've done so far, and doesn't have an Ubuntu build that works (and vice versa, you can't use Ubuntu `.deb` files on Solus).  This being said, you probably shouldn't be mixing and matching these either way, and if the applet you want is *not* Solus specific you could probably rewrite the applet to be 'standard' and not depend on Solus (but that's beyond the scope of this question)

Comment: Agreed! I guess I will switch over to a VM to build the applet then. Thanks for the great explaination and time. :)

Comment: @Rahul I am doubtful you need Solus specifically to build your applet.  If you frame another question I'm sure we can help with answering what ubuntu package will meet your dependency question.

Comment: @fossfreedom Yeah I guess, I will need Solus to build the applet. Thanks!

Comment: @Rahul Not necessarily, if the applet can get by without `eopkg`.  If the applet is pulling in `eopkg` dependencies though then you're out of luck.  But that's a different question than was being asked here...

Comment: Since the applets are for the budgie panel to be precise, they require `budgie` as a mandatory requirement and hence I guess Solus is the only way out. I will still ask in their Dev forums to get any help.

Comment: @Rahul well, "Budgie" is just a desktop environment, which stands to reason that `eopkg` is not a requirement (there's Ubuntu Budgie which has that desktop environment).  But again without more information it's impossible to really say if this is Solus only.

Comment: @Rahul You can build Budgie applets on Ubuntu Budgie too. If you are writing an applet following documentation or a tutorial that is for Solus, then they will tell you to use `eopkg`. Documentation or a tutorial for Ubuntu Budgie would tell you to use `apt`.